# pandas complex groupby, count and apply a cap

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Sample dataframe

```
> 0   location_day       payType    Name   ratePay      elapsedSeconds   
> 1   2019-12-10           PRE       Amy    12.25             199 
> 2   2019-12-12           PRE       Amy    12.25               7 
> 3   2019-12-17           PRE       Amy    12.25              68 
> 4   2019-12-17            RP       Amy     8.75              62
```

For each day, sum elapsedSeconds and calculate new column with total toPay (elapsedSeconds * ratePay) but apply a "cap" elapsedSeconds of 120. For any single day that only has 1 payType, apply cap so that only 120 is used to calculate "toPay" col.

But...

Also, groupby payType so that if there are 2 unique "payTypes" on a single day, sum the elapsedSeconds to determine if it's over the cap (120) and if so, subtract the elapsedSeconds from the last payType to make the sum equal to 120.

So I desire this output:

```
> 0   location_day       payType    Name   ratePay      elapsedSeconds  
> 1   2019-12-10           PRE       Amy    12.25             120    
> 2   2019-12-12           PRE       Amy    12.25               7  
> 3   2019-12-17           PRE       Amy    12.25              68  
> 4   2019-12-17            RP       Amy     8.75              52
```

I'm not quite sure how to approach this one and really only have performed some very basic grouping and testing of calculating new columns with conditional statements such as

```
finDfcalc1 = finDf.sort('location_day').groupby(flds)['elapsedSeconds'].sum().reset_index()
finDfcalc1.loc[finDfcalc1['elapsedSeconds'] < 120, 'elapsedSecondsOverage'] = finDfcalc1['elapsedSeconds'] * 1
finDfcalc1.loc[finDfcalc1['elapsedSeconds'] > 120, 'elapsedSecondsOverage'] = finDfcalc1['elapsedSeconds'] - 120
finDfcalc1['toPay'] = finDfcalc1['ratePay'] * finDfcalc1['elapsedSecondsOverage']
```

None of this has to be a one-liner and would be perfectly happy just working out the logic. All suggestions and ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to group on the day, calculate the cumsum of `'elapsedSeconds'` and then apply some logic to clip the total in a day at 120 seconds and then back calculate the correct # of seconds for all rows.

Here's a longer sample dataset to show how it behaves for an additional day with many rows that need to get changed.

```
location_day       payType    Name   ratePay      elapsedSeconds   
2019-12-10           PRE       Amy    12.25             199 
2019-12-12           PRE       Amy    12.25               7 
2019-12-17           PRE       Amy    12.25              68 
2019-12-17            RP       Amy     8.75              62
2019-12-18           PRE       Amy    12.25              50 
2019-12-18            RP       Amy     8.75              60
2019-12-18            RA       Amy     8.75              20
2019-12-18            RE       Amy     8.75              10
2019-12-18            XX       Amy     8.75              123
```

---

Code:

```
# Will become the seconds you want in the end
df['real_sec'] = df.groupby('location_day').elapsedSeconds.cumsum()

# Calculate a difference
m = df['real_sec'] - df['elapsedSeconds']

                                      #MagicNum
df['real_sec'] = (df['real_sec'].clip(upper=120)   # 120 at most
                  - m.where(m.gt(0)).fillna(0)     # only change rows where diff is positive
                 ).clip(lower=0)                   # Negative results -> 0
```

---

```
 location_day payType Name  ratePay  elapsedSeconds  real_sec
0   2019-12-10     PRE  Amy    12.25             199     120.0
1   2019-12-12     PRE  Amy    12.25               7       7.0
2   2019-12-17     PRE  Amy    12.25              68      68.0
3   2019-12-17      RP  Amy     8.75              62      52.0
4   2019-12-18     PRE  Amy    12.25              50      50.0
5   2019-12-18      RP  Amy     8.75              60      60.0
6   2019-12-18      RA  Amy     8.75              20      10.0
7   2019-12-18      RE  Amy     8.75              10       0.0
8   2019-12-18      XX  Amy     8.75             123       0.0
```

Comment: There are probably other ways, This get pretty tricky. I *think* this logic works, but haven't fully thought about all test cases. Ofc with things like this good unit tests are always the best. I added the one obvious case that was missing, but haven't thought about if there are others.

Comment: I appreciate that and this is what i need to just get started, even if this isn't the full correct logic. It's very much what I needed at this point.  Thank you I will follow up asap or mark correct asap.